# emails is sent multiple times with phpemailer

Tags: php, php-5.5

I'm trying to use the phpemailer  to send emails from my server. It's working fine except one thing:

```
<?php

$serverName = "xxx.x.x.xxx"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test", "UID"=>"xxxxxx", "PWD"=>"xxxxxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


$sqll=sqlsrv_query($conn,"select bla from table");


//while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql))

//  {

    //  $cnp=substr($row['bla'],-6);

//      echo $bla;
//      echo "<br>";

//  }
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");


$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from table");



if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){


    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "xxxxxx";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = xxx;

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "xxxxxx";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('xxxxxx');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('xxxxxx');
//Set who the message is to be sent to



while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))

    {
        echo $row['bla'];
        echo "<br>";


        $mail->AddBCC($row['bla2']);



//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'text text';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->Body = "test test<br>link:<a href='http://localhost:8181/?cod=".$bla."'>click</a>";



$mail->IsHTML(true); 




 $mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }


    }


}
?>

<form name="contact" method="post" action="">

<input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The problem is: I'm trying to send an email with a different link to every email I've got in my database. I had put this part between the while:

```
$mail->AddBCC($row['email']);



//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'text text';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->Body = "test test<br>link:<a href='http://localhost:8181/?cod=".$bla."'>click</a>";



$mail->IsHTML(true); 




 $mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }


    }
```

The emails are being sent but for example if i have 3 emails in my table then  to email1 is sent the email 3 times, to email2 is sent 2 times and the email3 is sent one time. Why is that? why does the email being sent 3 times to the first email in my table?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but please don't say that those are your real mail credentials you included in the script above? And why are you connecting to my sql server and mysql?

Comment: Just use `$mail->setAddress($row['email'])` instead of `$mail->addBCC()`

Comment: it's just dummy data from my localhost server xampp..

Comment: @DrKey Id' assume BCC is very important here.

Comment: yes..BCC is important

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is that you are adding the emails to the BCC, therefore, in the first loop, you are sending it to the first email, on the second, you are sending to the first email, and the newly added second email, and... so on...

You should clean the bcc before adding a new email.

Answer (score 0):

call `$mail->ClearBCCs()` after `$mail->send()`

> Clears all recipients assigned in the BCC array. Returns void.

--or--

Move your `$mail->send()` to after the loop to send all BCC addressed emails at once. *(you may need to do this in batches depending on the mail server)*

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following line after I send the email:

```
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
```

And now the emails are sent sent only one time. Thanks to all!